# Can't reprogram keyboard multimedia button

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

OK, I've spent hours trying to figure this problem out: I bought a new keyboard, the cherry mx board 3.0 to be specific, and it has a key on the top right which opens the browser. I've been trying to figure out how to reprogram that to be a pause/play button, now I've tried various reprogramming software like SharpKeys, that didn't work, I've tried editing the regedit manually, luckily I know a tiny bit about programming; anyways that didn't work. So then i found a cherry keyboard software from cherry itself, and I edited the key there, and now the same button opens the browser and Windows media Player, which I don't use for my music, but either way, it still opens the web browser no matter if it opens Media Player or not. Nothing seems to work and I can't use AutoHotkey to do it because the games I play will flag it and shut down. Does anyone have any idea how to stop the button from launching the browser and to actually make it be a play/pause button. Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

i can repgram the button using the cherry's software but itll still load the browser and windows media player at the same time, so it designates the key to use play/pause of windows media player, and  at the same time still opens the web browser.

[screenshot of the cherry software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j01b0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

*edit: This information is not all correct - check comments*

If [this](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/accessories/keyboards/1401583/cherry-mx-board-30-review) is your keyboard, then I believe that it cannot be rebound.
When the button is pressed, the keyboard's firmware will send a signal to the computer saying to open the default browser, there is no software dictating what the button does.
I have installed the Cherry MX 3.0 software, and can't make sense of it. As far as I can see, ***there is no rebinding the button.***

Comment: i can repgram the button using the cherry's software but itll still load the browser and windows media player